# Profiler engine warning throws by Netbeans Memory Profiler

Tags: java, netbeans, jvm, profiler, glassfish-4

I am trying to use Netbeans profiler, although I can run Profiler monitor but when I run Profiler Memory it shows the following errors in console under GlasshFish4 window.

```
*** Profiler engine warning: class sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor107 that should be instrumented is not loaded by target VM
SEVERE:   *** Requested classloader: sun.reflect.DelegatingClassLoader@554f6057
SEVERE:   , its class = class sun.reflect.DelegatingClassLoader, index = 354, hashcode = 1431265367
SEVERE:   *** Profiler engine warning: target VM cannot load class to instrument sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor107
SEVERE:   *** probably it has been unloaded recently
SEVERE:   *** Profiler engine warning: class sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor108 that should be instrumented is not loaded by target VM
SEVERE:   *** Requested classloader: sun.reflect.DelegatingClassLoader@25bb0b75
SEVERE:   , its class = class sun.reflect.DelegatingClassLoader, index = 355, hashcode = 633015157
SEVERE:   *** Profiler engine warning: target VM cannot load class to instrument sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor108
SEVERE:   *** probably it has been unloaded recently
SEVERE:   *** Profiler engine warning: class sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor109 that should be instrumented is not loaded by target VM
SEVERE:   *** Requested classloader: sun.reflect.DelegatingClassLoader@44540a55
SEVERE:   , its class = class sun.reflect.DelegatingClassLoader, index = 356, hashcode = 1146358357
SEVERE:   *** Profiler engine warning: target VM cannot load class to instrument sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor109
SEVERE:   *** probably it has been unloaded recently
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112666/how-to-interpret-profiling-results/20258821#20258821

Comment: @VickyThakor thats my other question ! answer is not about this error.

Comment: What I meant is use `VisualVM` rather then netbeans's profiler

Comment: The problem by VM is that it does not show the name of project but glassfish only

Comment: `VisualVM` supports profiler for specific classes as well.

Comment: do you know of any comprehensive tutorial that I can learn from ?

Answer (score 0):

These are not errors, per-se. These are warnings about the profiler engine not being able to transform various synthetic classes generated by the app server container. The profiler keeps on working just fine.

Also, switching to VisualVm wouldn't change anything since the same engine is used.